# How to extend the django User model?

Tags: python, django, model

I'm trying to implement the `Users` class from `django.contrib.auth.models` like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Registration(models.Model):
    '''Represents a user registration.'''
    user              = models.ForeignKey(User)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, help_text='The date of the registration')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.user, self.registration_date,)
```

This user have two attributes enabled by default: *username, password*

[image: screenshoot]

Reading at [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py) I can see that there are more attributes, like name and email.

How can I *enable* those *hidden* (if this is correct) attributes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, these attributes are not hidden. Assuming you have "django.contrib.auth" and "django.contrib.contenttypes" in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you have access to the `User` model as it is defined in your link. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) for the documentation on how to use/access it.

However, since you specified *extending* the `User` model, I expect you wanted to add some of your own fields to it (even though your example `registration_date` exists and is accessible via `myuser.date_joined`).

---

The older, more stable and more common way of doing this is similar to what you have. The only difference is to use a `OneToOneField(User)` instead of a `ForeignKey(User)`. This makes the relationship bidirectional and more convenient by forcing one. You do need to make sure and create a `Registration` object for every `User` created.

In fact, there is [an example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) of exactly what you want in the docs for the OneToOneField.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> registration = Registration.objects.create(user=user)
>>> user.registration.registration_date
# Should give the current time
>>> user.get_full_name()
# Should also have all those *hidden* attributes linked above
```

---

As of Django 1.5, you can use your own custom User model fairly easily. The documentation for this feature is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). If you are just adding some extra fields, then you can subclass the User model and add your own fields.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    # We inherit all those nifty things from AbstractUser
    registration_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then enable it in your settings.py by adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`. We now have to access the user model a little differently

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model()
>>> Users = get_user_model()
>>> user = Users.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> user.registration_date
# Should give the current time
>>> user.get_full_name()
# Should have those 'hidden' attributes
```

---

All this is available under [extending](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user) and [substituting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) the User model in the documentation.

Comment: But who can I enter those attributes from the *Add a New User* form? For instance, you can see in my screenshoot that I only can enter a username and password, but I want to use name, email and others too. This attributes are on the default models, so I don't want to overwrite them.

Comment: @Lucio I see, your question is about extending the django admin form. Take a look at the full-example at the bottom [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-user), particularly where it says "the following code would be required in the app's admin.py file". I'll update my post when I get time to test it.